# Database lightbox with jquery only showing first entry of the database

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, database, pdo

I'm trying to make a page that gets entries from a database and displays them in a `<div>` called "gallery-item". However the lightbox works, it only shows the first entry of the database. I hope someone can make sense of this code and may be able to help me with my problem.

My html/php/sql

```
<?php if (isset($_POST["Website"])) {
            $query=$db->prepare("SELECT * FROM `portfoliodb`.`website`");
            $query->execute();

            while   ( $row = $query->fetch()){
                $website_id = $row['website_id'];
                $website_name = $row ['website_name'];
                $website_desc_en = $row ['website_desc_en'];
                $website_tags = $row ['website_tags'];
                $website_image = $row ['website_image'];
                $website_type = $row['website_type'];
                echo'
                    <div class="background hidden" id="background"></div>
                        <a>
                            <div class="lightbox hidden" id="lightbox">
                                <div class="box-title hidden" id="box-title">
                                    <h4 class="hidden" id="box-title-h">' . htmlspecialchars($website_name) . '</h4>
                                    <h4 class="close hidden" id="close">X</h4>
                                </div>
                                <div class="box-img hidden" id="box-img">

                                </div>
                                <div class="box-foot hidden" id="box-foot">
                                    <div class="box-space hidden" id="box-space"></div>
                                    <div class="box-desc hidden" id="box-desc">
                                        <p class="desc-text hidden" id="box-text">'. htmlspecialchars($website_desc_en) .' </p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="tag-space-box hidden" id="box-tags-space"></div>
                                    <div class="tag-box hidden" id="box-tags">
                                        <small id="box-small" class="hidden">'. htmlspecialchars($website_tags) .'</small>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    <a>
                    <div class="gallery-item-web button" id="button">
                        <p class="gallary-item-text">';
                echo htmlspecialchars($website_name);
                echo'</p>';
                echo '<i class="fa fa-desktop fa-3x position-icon"></i>
                        </div></a>
                        ';
            }}
```

The gallery shows all entries in the database so that works fine, the only problem is that the lightbox shows the first entry, so if I were to have a database with the entries "Apples, Pears, Oranges", the gallery would display "Apples, Pears, Oranges". But the lightbox would display "Apples" on every single entry.

My Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".button").click(function(){
    $("#background").toggleClass("hidden");
    $("#lightbox").toggleClass("hidden");
    $("#box-title").toggleClass("hidden");
    $("#box-title-h").toggleClass("hidden");
    $(".close").toggleClass("hidden");
    $("#box-img").toggleClass("hidden");
    $("#box-foot").toggleClass("hidden");
    $("#box-space").toggleClass("hidden");
    $("#box-desc").toggleClass("hidden");
    $("#box-text").toggleClass("hidden");
    $("#box-tags-space").toggleClass("hidden");
    $("#box-tags").toggleClass("hidden");
    $("#box-small").toggleClass("hidden");
});
$(".close").click(function(){
    $("#background").toggleClass("hidden");
    $("#lightbox").toggleClass("hidden");
    $("#box-title").toggleClass("hidden");
    $("#box-title-h").toggleClass("hidden");
    $(".close").toggleClass("hidden");
    $("#box-img").toggleClass("hidden");
    $("#box-foot").toggleClass("hidden");
    $("#box-space").toggleClass("hidden");
    $("#box-desc").toggleClass("hidden");
    $("#box-text").toggleClass("hidden");
    $("#box-tags-space").toggleClass("hidden");
    $("#box-tags").toggleClass("hidden");
    $("#box-small").toggleClass("hidden");
});
$(".background").click(function(){
    $("#background").toggleClass("hidden");
    $("#lightbox").toggleClass("hidden");
    $("#box-title").toggleClass("hidden");
    $("#box-title-h").toggleClass("hidden");
    $(".close").toggleClass("hidden");
    $("#box-img").toggleClass("hidden");
    $("#box-foot").toggleClass("hidden");
    $("#box-space").toggleClass("hidden");
    $("#box-desc").toggleClass("hidden");
    $("#box-text").toggleClass("hidden");
    $("#box-tags-space").toggleClass("hidden");
    $("#box-tags").toggleClass("hidden");
    $("#box-small").toggleClass("hidden");
});
```

});

(It's pretty bad I know, this is my first time using Jquery)

This is the Jquery for the lightbox, it toggles the class on every item of the lightbox to "hidden". Whih basically makes every item with that class invisible, great for a lightbox.

Comment: "It's pretty bad" I don't know - I've seen (and written) a lot worse!!

Comment: Thank you, makes me feel a lot more confident.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, you don't need to add class of "hidden" to every element. You can just add it to the container element and then all tags inside would also be hidden.

Your main mistake was to have the same ids and classes for all images, you will need to ensure that each image has an unique identifier.

Try my solution: https://jsfiddle.net/3vhv90ce/2/

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container1">
    <div class="background" id="background"></div>
        <a>
            <div class="lightbox" id="lightbox">
                <div class="box-title" id="box-title">
                    <h4 class="" id="box-title-h">name</h4>
                    <h4 class="close" id="close">X</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="box-img" id="box-img">

                </div>
                <div class="box-foot" id="box-foot">
                    <div class="box-space" id="box-space"></div>
                    <div class="box-desc" id="box-desc">
                        <p class="desc-text" id="box-text">description</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="tag-space-box" id="box-tags-space"></div>
                    <div class="tag-box" id="box-tags">
                        <small id="box-small" class="">tags</small>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="gallery-item-web button" data-id="1">
    <p class="gallary-item-text">Click me</p>
    <i class="fa fa-desktop fa-3x position-icon"></i>
</div>

<div class="container2">
    <div class="background" id="background"></div>
        <a>
            <div class="lightbox" id="lightbox">
                <div class="box-title" id="box-title">
                    <h4 class="" id="box-title-h">name</h4>
                    <h4 class="close" id="close">X</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="box-img" id="box-img">

                </div>
                <div class="box-foot" id="box-foot">
                    <div class="box-space" id="box-space"></div>
                    <div class="box-desc" id="box-desc">
                        <p class="desc-text" id="box-text">description</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="tag-space-box" id="box-tags-space"></div>
                    <div class="tag-box" id="box-tags">
                        <small id="box-small" class="">tags</small>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="gallery-item-web button" data-id="2">
    <p class="gallary-item-text">Click me</p>
    <i class="fa fa-desktop fa-3x position-icon"></i>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".button").click(function(){
        $('.container'+$(this).data('id')).toggleClass("hidden");
    });
});
```

**CSS:**

```
.hidden {
    display: none;
}
.gallery-item-web {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: First of all, thank you for your time. This is not a bad sollution when you use static html, but I am using a **database connection** for all information to be displayed in the lightbox and the gallery-item `divs`.  However the hidden class idea is great and I will give you credit for that, cleans up my jquery a bit aswell.

Comment: This would work just fine with a data from database, make sure that you increment `container1` class with every intereation so it will be somehting like: `<div class="container'.$website_id.'">`, same for data-id: `<div class="gallery-item-web button" data-id="'.$website_id.'"`

Answer (score 1):

I suppose your problem came from those lines:

```
<div class="background hidden" id="background"></div>

<div class="gallery-item-web button" id="button">
```

you have many `controls` with the same `id`, And this is ambiguous for jQuery.

Comment: Thank you for your time, I will look into your answer and come back to you when I tried this.

Comment: I tried your sollution but it didn't seem to fix the problem, but thanks for your time and answer.

Comment: You are welcome, even though I didn't told you any solution.
The solution will be two steps:
1- change IDs for divs.
2- change `$("#background").toggleClass("hidden")` like those to pointer at new ID.
 Also you can search for control by name